# Preventing type-variable proliferation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, existential-type

Parameterizing out type variables is nice, but it doesn't scale. As an example of what can happen, http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2017-04-26-indexed-poptics.html gives an abstraction containing 9 type variables. I have been working on a framework for program transformations which are parameterized by the programming language, and could quite conceivable have dozens or hundreds of parameters in the future.

So here's the basic question: **I have a datatype T which is parameterized over N types. How can I write a function over T, without writing down N type variables every time I use it?**

Here are some approaches I've looked at, none of which are satisfiable:

**Parameterize over type variables of kind `* -> *`**

```
data V = Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4

myfunc :: forall (v :: V -> *). Constraints v => v Var1 -> v Var2
myfunc = ...
```

So, now, instead of parameterizing over 4 type variables `Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4`, I need only parameterize over one type variable of kind `V -> *`.

This works, except that, in this example, `myfunc` can't be called because `v` can't be inferred. You would need to change it to `Proxy v -> v Var1 -> v Var2`. And then, every time you want to use `myfunc` with difference variables, you would need to define a separate GADT, with its own boilerplate. Something like this:

```
data MyV a where
  MyVar1 :: Int -> MyV Var1
  MyVar2 :: String -> MyV Var2
  MyVar3 :: Bool -> MyV Var3
  MyVar4 :: [Int] -> MyV Var4
```

Needless to say, this is very unsatisfying.

This approach is exactly the one taken by the multi-sorted parts of the [compdata library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata). It's quite nice there, because this boilerplate lines up exactly with the normal datatype you'd be writing anyway.

**Parameterize over type variable of kind `(*,*,*,...)` or a record kind**

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}
import Data.Kind

type Vars = (*,*,*,*)

myfunc :: forall (v :: Vars). ...
myfunc = ...
```

This doesn't work, because, as far as I can tell, there's no way to destruct a type variable `v` of kind `(*,*,*,*)` . I can create an instance `(Int, String, Bool, [Int])`, but I can't actually extract the components Int, String, etc. The best I can do is write a type family:

```
type family Fst (v :: Vars) where
  Fst '(a,b,c,d) = a
type family Snd ....

myfunc :: forall (v :: Vars). Fst Vars -> Snd Vars
```

However, this has the same problem as the previous solution: it can't infer `v` unless you pass in a `Proxy v` separately. I also tried adding a constraint `type Extensional v = (v ~ '(Fst v, Snd v, Third v, Fourth v))`, but it didn't help.

**Using existentially-quantified variables**

```
data HasFourTypeVariables a b c d = ....
data IOnlyCareAboutTwo a b = forall c d. IOnlyCareAboutTwo (HasFourTypeVariables a b c d)
```

This doesn't work. Here's what it looks like when you tried to use it:

```
update :: IOnlyCareAboutTwo a b -> IOnlyCareAboutTwo a b
update = ...

useUpdate :: HasFourTypeVariables a b c d -> HasFourTypeVariables a b c d
useUpdate x = case update (IOnlyCareAboutTwo x) of
                IOnlyCareAboutTwo y -> y
```

This doesn't typecheck, because the typechecker doesn't know that the input and output of `update` have the same existential witnesses.

**Use Backpack**

Backpack looks like the best contender so far. Depending on a module signature with 5 types and associated operations/constraints is kinda like having 5 universally-quantified constrained type variables in every operation, except you don't need to write them down.

Backpack is still fairly new, and not yet integrated with Stack; I don't yet have any experience with it. Also, it seems to be built for parameterizing over entire packages rather than smaller units of functionality; I'm under the impression that it has poor support for the kind of explicit instantiation that would be required here.

**Have a long list of type variables, and put up with it**

Solution I'm considering doing. :(

---

**Some Background**

This problem is threatening to arise in my work on multi-language program transformation, extending https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.04600.pdf .

In my system, a term in a programming language has a type `Term f l`, where `f` is a signature for a programming language (of kind `(*->*)->(*->*)` -- see [the CDTs paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4c78/1b880cdda553301777bad192d2e6928e957a.pdf) for explanation), and `l` is a sort. So, a statement in C may have type `Term CSig StmtL`, while a Java expression may have type `Term Java ExpL`.

So far, this is just two type variables. But, as I push the system into more generality and the ability to abstract over deeper and deeper semantic properties, the number of type variables may explode. Here are some examples of how:

1. I want to store annotations on AST nodes. Some, like a node label and its source origin, are decent ideas to have on every tree, but others, like symbol resolution, or mark of whether that subtree has been modified, are desirable in some trees but not others. I'd hence like my representations to be able to flexibly add annotations in some representations but not others, and to be able to write operators that only care whether a subset of these annotations are present. How to do this? One or many type variables for annotations, along with a lot of "HasSymbolResolutionAnnotation a" constraints.
2. After a lot of experience, and many hours of reflection, I've decided that mutable ASTs are actually a pretty good idea. I'd then like to be able to write operators that can work on both pure and mutable ASTs. I haven't yet figured out how best to do this, but you can bet it will add at least one type variable to my type.
3. Within that `CSig` or `JavaSig` signature, there may be many language-generic nodes, like "Add." For many simple analyses and transformations, it's enough just to say "this language has addition" and stick in a generic Add node. But for more complicated ones, it may matter whether addition in your language can overflow and how, whether the (+) operator is a primitive or can be overridden like in C++ or Haskell, and what constraints it places on the surrounding types. Now, instead of an "Add" node, your language may have an `Add MonomorphicAddition NonOverridable OverflowWrapsToNegative` node, and your analysis-of-signs defines transfer functions for languages with an `Add a b OverflowWrapsToNegative` node. There is no limit on the number of variations of an operator you can encode like this. And as long as there are many useful things you can say about such a parameterized operator that only reference a couple of its parameters, it will be desirable to treat them this way.

I hope this helps explain why this is a problem.

Comment: All of your `Proxy` based woes are avoidable via `TypeApplication`. You _can_ extract elements of a tuple of types: use equality constraints: `v ~ (t1, t2, t3, t4)`. Backpack and existential types don't make any sense here. This question would be a bit clearer if you added an example of your types with many type variables and how you are using them. I reckon there is probably something off - 9 type variable types are not exactly common... In fact, that post by Oleg is the only such real life example I've seen.

Comment: I'll need to get GHC 8.0 working on my computer to test this, but it looks like you still need to write down 5 variables to extract a component of a 4-tuple, meaning there's no abstraction over the number of variables needed, which defeats the point of using a tuple. Why doesn't Backpack make sense here? To me it seems like the most promising approach so far. Anyway, I've added several pargraphs explaining why I care about this problem.

Comment: Perhaps the Trees that Grow approach could help: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/trees-that-grow.pdf

Comment: Just put your type variables in a record. If you’re unsure how, I can make an answer with an example.

Comment: After your edit: (1) and (2) ought both add a type variable (for (2), I recommend you wrap recursive ASTs with an `m` type constructor over which your parametrize. Then, you can let `m ~ IORef` to make everything mutable, or `m ~ Identity` to keep it immutable), but (3) sounds like it might be better solved otherwise (without type variables). I might take a look tomorrow. In any case, it still sounds like you should list out your type variables manually.

Comment: I don't understand the objections you make to the first two solutions. In practice functions will take some `AST v` and that's how `v` will be inferred. +1 for trees that grow.

Comment: @augustss I would like to know about the record solution.

Comment: I also want to see the record solution. I had Googled around for type records in Haskell and tried some things, but had been left with the impression that GHC doesn't support type-level records.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia: The short version is: The type inference doesn't work.

Comment: @Alec: Does explicit type application help when you have a type class where not every method mentions every type variable? I can't find anything on this. If that's not the case, then no, explicit type applications don't solve all my Proxy woes.

Answer (score 3):

This answer was inspired by the [Trees That Grow](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/trees-that-grow.pdf) paper. It assumes that there exist only a limited number of "variants" of the data type, that only a small subset of all possible instantiations of **N** parameters are used.

```
{-# language DataKinds #-}
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language KindSignatures #-}
{-# language PolyKinds #-}
{-# language FlexibleContexts #-}
```

We define our data type like this

```
data MyType (v::Variant) = MyType (Xa v) (Xb v) (Xc v) Int

data Variant = V1 | V2

type family Xa (v::Variant) :: * where
    Xa V1 = Int
    Xa V2 = Bool

type family Xb (v::Variant) :: * where
    Xb V1 = Bool
    Xb V2 = Char

type family Xc (v::Variant) :: * where
    Xc V1 = String
    Xc V2 = Maybe Int
```

There are two "variants" of the data type. Each changing field has its own (admittedly boilerplatery) type family which maps a variant to the actual type of the field in that variant.

Here's a simple function which works for all variants of the data type:

```
getInt :: MyType (v :: Variant) -> Int
getInt (MyType _ _ _ i) = i
```

With `-XConstraintKinds` we can define a constraint shared by all fields:

```
{-# language ConstraintKinds #-}
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
type MyForAll (p :: * -> Constraint) (v::Variant) = (p (Xa v),p (Xb v),p (Xc v))
```

We can use it to define functions like

```
myShow :: MyForAll Show (v :: Variant) => MyType v -> String
myShow (MyType a b c i) = show a ++ show b ++ show c ++ show i
```

We can also enable `-XTypeApplications` to specify the variant:

```
λ :t MyType
MyType :: forall {v :: Variant}. Xa v -> Xb v -> Xc v -> Int -> MyType v
λ :set -XTypeApplications
λ :t MyType @V1
MyType @V1 :: Int -> Bool -> String -> Int -> MyType 'V1
```

Comment: Thank you, danidiaz. Both this and augustss's answers have a similar flavor. They look appealing, but we know all kinds of problems crop up when trying to do higher-order type-level programming. I'll report back once I've tried them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group a number of type variables together you can do that.
On the value level you would just use a record, and you can do that on the type level too.  Create a record type, and then the lifted version of that can be used to group types.  Record access gets a bit clunky since the value level record selector syntax does not lift.

Here's an example that should clarify what I mean.

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, TypeInType, UndecidableInstances #-}
module RecordTyVars where
import Data.Kind

-- The normal way, with 3 type variables.
data OExpr sym lit op = OVar sym | OLit lit | OPrimOp op [OExpr sym lit op]
     deriving (Show)

oe :: OExpr String Integer Op
oe = OPrimOp Add [OVar "x", OLit 1]

data Op = Add | Sub
     deriving (Show)

--------

-- Record that when lifted will contain the types.
data ExprTypes = Types Type Type Type

-- Record access functions, since the record syntax doesn't lift.
type family SymType (r :: ExprTypes) :: * where
    SymType ('Types sym lit op) = sym
type family LitType (r :: ExprTypes) :: * where
    LitType ('Types sym lit op) = lit
type family OpType (r :: ExprTypes) :: * where
    OpType  ('Types sym lit op) = op

-- Using the record of types
data Expr r = Var (SymType r) | Lit (LitType r) | PrimOp (OpType r) [Expr r]

-- Must use standalone deriving when thing the going gets tough.
deriving instance (Show (SymType r), Show (LitType r), Show (OpType r)) =>
                  Show (Expr r)

e :: Expr ('Types String Integer Op)
e = PrimOp Add [Var "x", Lit 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, augustss. Both this and dandiaz's answers have a similar flavor. They look appealing, but we know all kinds of problems crop up when trying to do higher-order type-level programming. I'll report back once I've tried them.

Comment: Relative to my answer, in this approach it's easier to write functions that change a type independently of the others.